# The meaning of $N_{K/K(a)}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

I am in the proof of the theorem of Artin-Schreier, where $K$ is a field with $\text{char}(K)=p$, and $p$ is a prime number. There I have discovered the following notation:

$$N_{K(a)/K}(\beta)$$

What does it mean?

Comment: By the way, currently the title says $N_{K/K(a)}$. I assume this should be $N_{K(a)/K}$...? If so, please edit your question so that it says so

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's the *field norm*:

If $L\supseteq K$ is a finite field extension, then multiplication by some $x\in L$ can be given in matrix form. The determinant of this matrix is $N_{L/K}(x)$, the field norm.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_norm) (etc.) for more information.